# what limits the index for listview.getChildAt(index)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

When I call `listview.getChildAt(index)`, what should `index` be for me to get a non-null value back? Must `index` be a value in the range `[0, listview.getChildCount() )` or in the range  `[0, adapter.getCount() )`. This is a follow up question from [listview count vs adapter count in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142694/listview-count-vs-adapter-count-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [0, listview.getChildCount() ) or wrap in a `try/catch` because this could give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. However, if you are getting a `null` value then it is probably because the `ListView` isn't done drawing yet. You will want to post a `Runnable` to solve this.

For example, this is how I get the count and decide if there are more items in the `List` than what is on the screen:

```
listView.post(new Runnable()
{       
    public void run()
    {
        int numItemsVisible = listView.getLastVisiblePosition() -
                                listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (itemsAdapter.getCount() - 1 > numItemsVisible && numItemsVisible > -1)
        {   //do stuff  }                                   
        else
        {   
            //do other stuff
        }               
    }
});
```

Comment: does the same go for getItem from the adapter? or is that, as I might expect, limited by `adapter.getCount()`? btw I will test and report back. +1

Comment: That will depend on the `Adapter` count, yes

Answer (score 0):

That would be `[0, listview.getChildCount() )`

Answer (score 0):

ListView is just view with childrens(rows). And range for getChildAt is  [0, listview.getChildCount()). ListView contains only view witch is visible now. Adapter getCount() return count of data rows, like maximum length of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

per my experiment, here is how it works. The ListView is a slice of the adapter. So if an adapter has 500 items and the ListView has ten (10). The ten in the ListView represent a dynamic view. So if the firstVisibleItem were item 217 in the adapter, then the ListView range of indices would be (217,…,226) whereas the listView.getChildCount() would still return 10.

Hence the answer is:

```
getChildAt(x) | x : [0+firstVisibleItem, listview.getChildCount()+firstVisibleItem)
```