# understanding ListView childAt method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

say I have an adapter with 145 items. And presently in my Listview I have 10 views showing, where the views represent items 104 to 113. Now I have a scrollListener whose onScroll method is

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
{
  View view = getViewForPosition(??, view);//keep reading for ?? details
}
```

If I need the view for my firstVisibleItem, which to the adapter is item 104, how do I request it from the list? Do I say `listview.getChildAt(0)`? Or do I say `listview.getChildAt(104)`?

Now in reality I am using the method below, but the essential questions stands.

```
public View getViewForPosition(int position, AbsListView listview) {
        int firstPosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition()
            - ((ListView) listview).getHeaderViewsCount();
        int wantedChild = position - firstPosition;
        // Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild will now be 2
        // So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
        if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= listview.getChildCount()) {
            return null;
        }
        return listview.getChildAt(wantedChild);
    }
```

Comment: I think a better question is, why do you need the view from the onScroll method? Not saying there couldn't be a reason, but usually most anything you would want to do you could do to a View, you can (and should) do in the `getView()` method.

Comment: @kcoppock I am glad you ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041222/finding-pixel-location-of-listview-item-seems-to-return-wrong-value

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "listview.getChildAt(0)" (IF AND ONLY IF the element 104 is the first element visible), the way ListView works is by reusing "rows" or elements created, hence it does some sort of spinning mechanism internally that populates your values, but when it comes to "childs" it will only have the number of elements visible at one time, and those are reused across all the elements.
So if you have 300 elemens, but you can only see 5 at a time, it means that the number of childs in the list view is 5 + 1 or 2 to do the "last" and "first" element effect...

Now if what you want is the actual element used to populate the view (not the view itself), what you have to do is get the adapter out of the listview and call the Adapter.getItem(104), that will give you the element used to populate the row...

Hope this helps...

Regards!

Comment: for some reason that does not seem true.

Comment: what exactly is not true?

Comment: `listview.getChildAt(0)` returns firstVisibleItem iff firstVisibleItem is index 0 is what works. I am trying to solve a bigger problem. The thing is I need to anticipate the null values and that is not happening.

Comment: If you need to manipulate info in listview before showing it to user, then you need to implemenet your own BaseAdapter, and in the getView method you will have the chance to do what u want...

Answer (score 0):

per my experiment, here is how it works. The ListView is a slice of the adapter. So if an adapter has 500 items and the ListView has ten (10). The ten in the ListView represent a dynamic view. So if the firstVisibleItem were item 217 in the adapter, then the ListView range of indices would be (217,…,226) whereas the listView.getChildCount() would still return 10.

Hence "listview.getChildAt(0)" would fail.